# VBA copy/paste range into rows below if there is a value in column a

Tags: vba, loops, variables, range, copy-paste

I am trying to create a macro that will copy a range of values say `B6:BM6` and paste it in the row below IF there is a value in column A.

So: if column `A6` is populated, copy range from rows above and paste them into `B6`. Loop until there is no value in column A.

```
Sub fillEmptycells()

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim lastRow As Integer

 With ActiveSheet
     lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  
     For i = 2 To lastRow
         If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 2)) And Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then
           .Range(Cells(i - 1, 2), Cells(i - 1, 100)).Copy .Cells(i, 2)
         End If
     Next i
 End With
End Sub
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: when `i=1` this `.Cells(i - 1, 2).Copy` will error since there is no row 0.  Start your loop at 2 not 1.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are only copying one cell, not a whole range. You need to change the range you call the Copy method on to include all of the cells you want to copy. The code in your If statement would be changed to something like:

```
 .Range(Cells(i-1,2),Cells(i-1,x)).Copy .Cells(i,2)
```

Where x would be the column number of the last column you want to copy.